# Convert list of trading days to holidays

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am using the function below which uses the list of trading days which seems to slow things down. Would it be possible to convert that list to the holidays instead to make it faster?

```
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
def next_trading_day(start_day, num_trading_days, direction):
    '''returns the next/previous trading day. Business_days determines how many days
    back or into the future, direction determines wether back (-1) or forward (1)'''
    for i in range(0, num_trading_days, direction):
        next_day = start_day +datetime.timedelta(days=direction)    
        while next_day.weekday() in [5,6] or next_day not in set(mcal.get_calendar('NYSE').valid_days(start_date='2016-12-20', end_date='2020-01-10')):
            next_day +=  datetime.timedelta(days=direction)
        start_day = next_day
    return start_day
```

Please note that I cannot use the other holidays functions that Python has to offer, since those are not related to trading days but rather federal holidays and the likes. So it has to be based on pandas_market_calendars.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

There is no need to iterate over each date. See this implementation:

> **Logic**:
>
> 1. Search for valid trading days in a date range. Use a date range that is larger than what you need (`num_trading_days`). We add `100` days additionally to extend the search-date-range.
> 2. Next we select the first `num_trading_days` from the available trading dates.
> 3. And select the last day of the first `num_trading_days` as the `next_day`.
> 4. Finally we return a tuple: `(next_day, valid_trading_days)`.

```py
#!pip install pandas_market_calendars
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def next_trading_day(start_day=None, num_trading_days=7, direction=1, SAFE_DELTA = 100, as_string=True):
    """Returns the next/previous trading date separated by a certain number of 
    trading days.

    This function returns the next/previous trading day. The parameter num_trading_days 
    determines how many days back or into the future, direction determines whether 
    backward (-1) or forward (1).
    Parameters
    ----------
    start_day: datetime.date or a str object. (default is today's UTC date).
        Date of starting day.
    num_trading_days: int. (default is 7)
    direction: int. (default is 1 (forward))
        Use 1 for forward/future and -1 for backward/past.
    as_string: bool (default is True)
        This controls the data type of the returned value of next_day. 
        Returns the next_day as a string if True, else as a datetime.date object.
    SAFE_DELTA: int. (default is 100)
        SAFE_DELTA = 100 adds 100 additional days to extend the range of dates and 
        then finds which dates are valid trading dates.

    Returns
    -------
    next_day: str or datetime.date object.
    valid_trading_days: pandas.Series object of datetime.date objects.
    """

    if start_day is None:
        start_day = datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()
    start = pd.to_datetime(start_day)
    end = start + np.timedelta64(num_trading_days+SAFE_DELTA, 'D')*direction
    business_days = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE').valid_days(start_date=start, end_date=end)
    valid_trading_days = pd.DataFrame(business_days[:num_trading_days], columns=['DT']).DT.dt.date
    next_day = business_days[num_trading_days].date()
    if as_string:
        next_day = next_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    # if the series of trading days from start_day to next_day are not required, 
    # then use: 
    # >>> valid_trading_days = None
    # You may also comment out the valid_trading_days variable creation line above. 
    # And change the function-output accordingly.
    return (next_day, valid_trading_days)
```

> ### Test

```py
start_day='2019-12-18' # (Wednesday)
num_trading_days = 7
next_day, valid_trading_days = next_trading_day(start_day = start_day, 
                                                num_trading_days = num_trading_days, 
                                                direction = 1, 
                                                SAFE_DELTA = 100)
print('next_day: {} (after {} trading days)\n'.format(next_day, num_trading_days))
print('valid_trading_days: \n\n{}'.format(valid_trading_days))
```

**Output**:

```
next_day: 2019-12-30 (after 7 trading days)

valid_trading_days: 

0    2019-12-18
1    2019-12-19
2    2019-12-20
3    2019-12-23
4    2019-12-24
5    2019-12-26
6    2019-12-27
Name: DT, dtype: object
```

Comment: @Tartaglia Please try out this and let me know if you have questions.